# UISearchDisplayController - display search results from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm stuck with the problem of trying to show search results in my `UISearchDisplayController` and table view controller.

I have REST API server endpoint for getting search results, I'm sending request when user clicks Search button and try to populate array of items into search display controller.. Unfortunately controller behaves very strange..

Here is the code of my Table View Controller, in **viewDidLoad** method I'm initializing search:

```
LSDropdownViewController *menuCtrl = (LSDropdownViewController *)[self parentViewController];

[self setSearchBar:menuCtrl.topSearchBar];
[self.searchBar setDelegate:self];
[self.searchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithGradientColors]];

// set search cancel button color
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:menuCtrl.topSearchBar contentsController:self];

[self.searchController setDelegate:self];
[self.searchController setSearchResultsDataSource:self.tableView.dataSource];
[self.searchController setSearchResultsDelegate:self.tableView.delegate];
```

I do request on click as follows:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
MyHTTPClient *api = [MyHTTPClient create];
[api searchPopularCollectionsByText:searchBar.text success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id collections) {
        [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
        NSArray *data = [collections objectForKey:@"data"];
        if ([data count] > 0) {
            NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (NSDictionary *collectionData in data) {
                LSCollection *collection = [[LSCollection alloc] initWithDictionary:collectionData];
                [result addObject:collection];
            }

            [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:result];
            [self.searchController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];

            [result removeAllObjects];
            result = nil;
        }
} failure:nil];
}
```

If response contains array of items I populate it inside `searchResults` array, and inside other methods I check for proper array of data (for example in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"collectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

LSCollection *collection;
if (tableView == self.searchController.searchResultsTableView) {
    collection = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    collection = [self.collections objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

...
```

But take a look on screencast, sometime `searchResults` is not populated..

**VIDEO** http://screencast.com/t/enImJQuA

Even more table view with search results position is not fixed and you can scroll down to original list as well.

What mistakes can be here? And what is the proper way to handle search on click with REST servers?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsForSection` methods properly deal with providing the right values for both table views?

Comment: @rmaddy I think so, in both methods I check which table view is currently active - ``if (tableView == self.searchController.searchResultsTableView)``

Comment: I want to implement the same thing could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Are the tableview delegate methods at same viewcontroller as  "searchBarSearchButtonClicked" method ? Try

```
[self.searchController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];
[self.searchController setSearchResultsDelegate:self];
```

If doesnt work tell me more about tableview delegate methods. Are they running ?

Comment: what table delegate methods do you mean?

Comment: my mistake. I use table datasource in same viewcontroller as searchdisplay controller - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPat

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath is called when results are populated, the problem is that they do not somehow..

Comment: i think you are populating other tableview than not searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView